# Clojure threading first macro -> with Math/pow or any other multiple args function

Tags: clojure, macros

How to write in one line the following code:

```
(-> 10 pow9)
```

where pow9 is:

```
(def pow9 (partial #(Math/pow % 9)))
```

If I write `(-> 10 (partial #(Math/pow % 9)))` I will get back `#<core$partial$fn__4228 clojure.core$partial$fn__4228@62330c23>` instead, 
writing `(-> 10 #(Math/pow % 9))` fails with `CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.ISeq, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)`,

although `(-> 10 pow9)` works fine.

The more general question is how to use -> with function which accepts more than one argument, i.e. how to make this work `(-> 10 #(+ % 10))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`->` inserts previous result as the **first parameter**, `->>` inserts previous result as the **last parameter**.

```
user=> (-> 10 (Math/pow 9))
1.0E9

user=> (-> 10 ((partial #(Math/pow % 9))))
1.0E9
```

Note the extra parens.

Actually you don't need partial here at all:

```
user=> (defn pow9 [x] (Math/pow x 9))
#'user/pow9
user=> (-> 10 pow9)
1.0E9
```

Answer (score 2):

The call simply is

```
user=> (-> 10 (Math/pow 9))
1.0E9
```

Because the `->` threading macro sends the result as first param.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the anonymous function to get called with the threaded item as its argument, you need another set of parens around it:

```
 (-> 10 (#(Math/pow % 9)))
```

This is because the macro inserts the item before the function definition (or partial application, or whatever you're doing) gets evaluated.